# what is the integral of an exponential function over the square of x?

Tags: integration, special-functions

What is the analytical solution of the following integral of $x$?
$$\int\frac{e^{\alpha{e}^{-(x-x_0)}}}{x^2}dx$$ 
where $\alpha$ and $x_{0}$ are constant.

Comment: no solution in terms of standard functions; look on wolframalpha if you just want an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have a series solution using
$$e^y=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {y^n} {n!}$$ Now, make $y=\alpha{e}^{-(x-x_0)}$ to face integrals
$$I_n=\int \frac{{e}^{-n(x-x_0)}}{x^2}\,dx=-\frac{e^{ nx_0} \left(n x \text{Ei}(-n x)+e^{-n x}\right)}{x}$$ where appear the [exponential integral function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral).

Comment: it seems that you miss the lower exponential. There are two exponentials in the function.

Comment: @WzS. I do not think so. Look at my definition of $y=\alpha{e}^{-(x-x_0)}$ and rewrite $e^y$. This is your expression.

Comment: where the factorial in the integral?

Comment: @WzS. You must introduce them since the final integral is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{I_n}{n!}$

Comment: you are right, one more question, the exponential integral function is not x square, how do you treat the x square in the denominator？